# How to create a IF command, via VBA, to sound a sentence?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create, via VBA, an "IF" command which would sound an specifc sentence when a pre determined condition is reached. Could you help me, please?

The only thing I know is that I need to use the "application.speech.speak" command. That is it.
PS: dear forum friends, as I am testing a suggested sent solution I ask you to wait a little while to see if it will work, avoiding taking your time. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe? You can use other conditions, of course.

```
Sub test()
If 1 = 1 Then
    Application.Speech.Speak ("hello world")
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Dear Tevlyn, thanks for your suggestion and time but unfortunately it didn't work. I thank you again anyway.

Comment: What did not work? Did you get an error? What code exactly did you use? What condition?

Comment: Dear Tevlyn, I believe it is better if I send you the sheet and explain what I need, ok? I will  do it later as I am writing from Brazil, 6:00 AM right now.